# Which font is used in Blender's logo?

Tags: interface

Here you can download the logo https://www.blender.org/about/logo/, but the text is not editable.

What font is? It's a free font, right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about using Blender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a special version of Helvetica. You can check the below links:

https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?67062-Official-Blender-font

https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?114438-Blender-s-Font

https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?90755-Blender-Font

Comment: Links are broken

Comment: @Edder sorry, I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

It is a <del>customized</del> hand-modified version of Helvetica....

https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?67062-Official-Blender-font